# Topics under Model Based Cluster Analysis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Can anyone recommended topic(s) I could use for my thesis under "Model Based Cluster Analysis"? I initially used "Inference in Model Based Cluster Analysis" as my working topic but appears to be broader than I expected. I want a topic I can relate with finding groups using model based cluster analysis. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What kind of thesis is it? A master's thesis?

Comment: @PAM, for doctoral studies in Statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good option, in my opinion, would be to focus for example on high-dimensional model-based clustering. It is a very active field which is somehow linked to all the current "big data" hype.

The main idea behind is that, to cluster efficiently high-dimensional data, you either have to

- assume that each group lives in a low-dimensional subspace (Tipping & Bishop, 1999)
- project the whole data on a single low-dimensional subspace (Bouveyron & Brunet, 2012)
- assume that only a few variables are truly relevant (Raftery & Dean, 2006)

A nice review is presented for instance by Bouveyron & Brunet-Saumard (2014). All these articles are freely available on their authors' webpages.

References.

Bouveyron, C., & Brunet, C. (2012). Simultaneous model-based clustering and visualization in the Fisher discriminative subspace. *Statistics and Computing*, 22(1), 301-324.

Bouveyron, C., & Brunet-Saumard, C. (2014). Model-based clustering of high-dimensional data: A review. *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, 71, 52-78.

Raftery, A. E. and Dean, N. (2006). Variable selection for model-based clustering. *Journal of the American Statistical
Association*, 101:168–178.

Tipping, M., & Bishop, C. (1999). Mixtures of probabilistic principal component analyzers. *Neural computation*, 11(2), 443-482.

Comment: this definitely helps. I am considering doctoral studies in Statistics and have been struggling coming out with a good topic for my research proposal. I would work around the guidelines you just provided. It definitely helps.